# (Sensenet) How to Create Folder with Name and Display Name are different from Dotnet Client(sn-client-dotnet)?

Tags: c#, sensenet

I can create folder by using this code:

```
var myFolder = Content.CreateNew("/Root/Sites/Default_Site", "Folder", "MyFolder");
await myFolder.SaveAsync();
```

How to make the Folder's name and it's display name are different using dotnet client?

example:

Display Name = "MyFolder"

but

Folder Name = "0E8646EF-C8AC-4DB5-973E-9AC1F8A0172B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content["DisplayName"] = "MyFolder";
content["Name"] = "0E8646EF-C8AC-4DB5-973E-9AC1F8A0172B";
await content.SaveAsync();
```